# How to split connected letters in a file

Tags: python, encryption, split

I have large files contain cipher texts. the ciphers are connected like this

```
QJFQFJDOVRVLHSVUJNHTZDGLDOVGSAYFKFPSAJSOEGXCDHCDDEWGTUUFOVDGQUJD
```

my question is how can I split the letters so I can for loop each letter?

I'm trying this code but I get this error message

```
num = (ord(symbol)-k) % 126
```

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but list found"

```
with open(file) as f:
    translated = ''
    for s in f:
            symbol = s.split()
            print(symbol)
            num = (ord(symbol)-k) % 126

            if num < 32:
                    num += 95
            translated += chr(num)
    print(translated)
```

before adding `.split()` function I got this error message:

> "TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found"

with this code:

```
with open(file) as f:
    translated = ''
    for symbol in f:
            print(symbol)
            num = (ord(symbol)-k) % 126

            if num < 32:
                    num += 95
            translated += chr(num)
    print(translated)
```

My ciphert contains no white spaces

Thank you

Comment: `s` is the line in the file . . . you'll want to iterate over that, and python lets you iterate over strings directly (i.e. `for _ in s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your file to split (as there are no spaces or any other separators). If your file is not ridiculously large, read its content as a string and then process the string as a collection of characters:

```
data = open(file).read()
for char in data:
     #do something with your char, like ord(char)
```

If the file is large, read it piecewise with `.read(n)`, and you will still get strings to work with.